# How to get `git diff master` as unstaged edits in the branch I'm in?

Tags: git

Let's say I'm in branch `otherBranch`. This branched out of master a while back, but I've kept up to date with master every since by doing `git merge master`. Now I wish to "reset" this `otherBranch`, but I don't think `git reset master` get's me where I want. Basically I wish to have everything that `git diff master` shows me (while standing in `otherBranch`) as unstaged edits. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `git reset master` will do what you want.  This will reset the state of the branch in the repository to whatever is in `master`, but will not touch your working files: in other words, your modifications will now all appear as unstaged edits.

Note also that is often better to keep your feature branch up-to-date by rebasing it regularly on master, rather than merging master.  This avoids a large collection of merge commits (so that the only commits are your branch are changes that you have explicitly committed):

- ...edit some stuff...
- `git add ...`
- `git commit -m "i made some changes"`
- ...time passes...
- `git remote update`
- `git rebase origin/master`

Comment: Also, remember you can always test out this sort of thing first: just create a new branch (`git checkout -b testbranch`), try out the `git reset master`, and see if you get the behavior you were looking for.